# Scala Seq vs List performance

Tags: scala, jvm, scala-collections

So I am a bit perplexed. I have a piece of code in Scala (the exact code is not really all that important). I had all my methods written to take `Seq[T]`. These methods are mostly tail recursive and use the `Seq[T]` as an accumulator which is fed initially like `Seq()`. Interestingly enough, when I swap all the signature with the concrete `List()` implementation, I am observing three fold improvement in performance.

Isn't it the case that `Seq`'s default implementation is in fact an `immutable List` ? So if that is the case, what is really going on ?

Comment: Do you have some code that demonstrates this?

Comment: `Seq` default implementation is actually of an `ArrayBuffer`, not a `List`. The use case you have is actually tailor-made for `List`s, since they are implemented tail-recursively.

Comment: Could that result in such a huge performance difference ?

Comment: The default implementation of the default `Seq` is `List`. Could you show the code and how you call it?

Answer (score 4):

Calling `Seq(1,2,3)` and calling `List(1,2,3)` will both result in a `1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil`. The [`Seq.apply`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.1/src/library/scala/collection/generic/GenericCompanion.scala#L45) method is just a very generic method that looks like this:

```
def apply[A](elems: A*): CC[A] = {
  if (elems.isEmpty) empty[A]
  else {
    val b = newBuilder[A]
    b ++= elems
    b.result()
  }
}
```

`newBuilder` is the thing that sort of matters here. [That method](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.1/src/library/scala/collection/Seq.scala#L37) delegates to [`scala.collection.immutable.Seq.newBuilder`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.1/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Seq.scala#L46):

```
def newBuilder[A]: Builder[A, Seq[A]] = new mutable.ListBuffer
```

So the `Builder` for a `Seq` is a `mutable.ListBuffer`. A `Seq` gets constructed by appending the elements to the empty `ListBuffer` and then calling [`result`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.1/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/ListBuffer.scala#L304) on it, which is implemented like this:

```
def result: List[A] = toList

/** Converts this buffer to a list. Takes constant time. The buffer is
 *  copied lazily, the first time it is mutated.
 */
override def toList: List[A] = {
  exported = !isEmpty
  start
}
```

`List` also has a `ListBuffer` as `Builder`. It goes through a slightly different but similar building process. It is not going to make a big difference anyway, since I assume that most of your algorithm will consist of prepending things to a `Seq`, not calling `Seq.apply(...)` the whole time. Even if you did it shouldn't make much difference.

It's really not possible to say what is causing the behavior you're seeing without seeing the code that has that behavior.

Comment: According to your assumption that Seq.apply was just a List, and that it didn't make a big difference, you would actually be able to do something like that, right:
val sequence: LinearSeq[_] = Seq()
This should accordingly work since Seq is a List and List uses the LinearSeq trait. But it doesn't work and for this reason, it matters how you construct your sequences, especially if you need efficient tail access or tail recursive operations (i.e., methods performing iterations on the sequence).

Comment: No. `Seq()` returns a `List` but its static `return type` is `Seq`. That's why you can't assign it to a variable of type `LinearSeq`. Evaluate `Seq(1).getClass` and see what you get.

Comment: But to be clear I do agree it's better to just use `List` if you want the performance characteristics of a `List`.

Comment: I've just checked it with the debugger. I assumed Seq only to use the ListBuffer to build the sequence but not to process it and to use the less-optimized operations from Traversable, etc., but it turns out it actually accesses the optimized methods from the List and its traits. For all intents and purposes, you were completely right claiming List.apply to be replaceable with Seq.apply. You should always use the apply methods of the three Seq traits. There is no explanation for any performance deviations.